# Como usar a função inversa do jQuery para desfazer algo?

Tags: jquery, css-hover

Estou usando o código abaixo para aplicar um efeito e desfazer assim que o mouse for removido mas parece não funcionar e não mostra nenhuma mensagem de erro. Estou usando a versão 1.12.4 do jQuery.

```
$(".project").on("hover", 
    (function() {

        $(this).find(".sendProposal").removeClass("hide");
    }, 
    function(){

        $(this).find(".sendProposal").addClass("hide");   
    }
));
```

Comment: a classe .project é parent da classe .sendProposal ? Também tem que ver se a classe project ta pegando o hover, pode ser que ela esteja hidden ou pode estar havendo algum problema de size ou display.

Comment: @PedroMorais a classe .project é parent da classe .sendProposal !! Também ocorre o evento quando eu coloco só 1 function, então a classe .project tá recebendo o evento.

Answer (score 6):

`hover` não é um *handler* que o método [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) entende. Para isso, o jQuery disponibiliza os eventos [`mouseenter`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) e [`mouseleave`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/). Para facilitar a vida do desenvolvedor, existe o método [`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/). De acordo com a documentação,

```
$( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )
```

é uma abreviação de

```
$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );
```

Você pode escrever o método da seguinte forma:

```js
$(".project").hover(function() {
        $(this).find(".sendProposal").removeClass("hide");
    }, function(){
        $(this).find(".sendProposal").addClass("hide");   
    }
);
```

```css
.project{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.sendProposal{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="project">
  <div class="sendProposal hide"></div>
</div>
```

Como eu não sei a estrutura do seu CSS, inventei algumas coisas apenas com o intuito da exemplificação.

Neste exemplo, do jeito que está, existe ainda a possibilidade de usar o método [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/), o que torna o *snippet* mais elegante. Mas como não sei exatamente o que você quer fazer, talvez ele não atenda. De qualquer maneira, segue o mesmo exemplo, usando o método citado.

```js
$(".project").hover(function() {
  $(".sendProposal", this).toggleClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.project{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.sendProposal{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="project">
  <div class="sendProposal hide"></div>
</div>
```

Como bônus, veja como eu construí o seletor no segundo exemplo, sem usar o método `find()`. Essa é mais uma possibilidade que o jQuery oferece.

Você ainda poderia usar o pseudo-seletor [`::hover`](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/sel_hover.asp), e não depender do JS, mas aí já é outra história...

Answer (score 0):

Voce agrupou as duas funções em parenteses, tornando-as o 2o parametro da chamada à .on().

Assim, sua chamada ficou com 2 parâmetros:

```
.on('hover', (function(), function()))
```

Por isso que, removendo a 2a opção, a que resta funciona apenas como o hover-in, mas mantendo as duas como está, nada funciona, pois o resultado é um callback inválido para o 2o parametro de .on()

No caso do hover, pra mapear os dois eventos (hover-in e hover-out), voce precisa passá-los de uma maneira específica pra função `.on()`

```
  $(".project").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      $(this).find(".sendProposal").removeClass("hide");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $(this).find(".sendProposal").addClass("hide");
    }
  });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".project").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      $(this).find(".sendProposal").removeClass("hide");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $(this).find(".sendProposal").addClass("hide");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project">
  <h1>Projeto</h1>
  <p class="sendProposal hide">
    Enviar proposta
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Pode fornecer um exemplo funcional? Testei aqui e não funciona, mas posso estar errado...

Comment: Atualizei a resposta e corrigi o trecho de código.